# React Native Testing - Full application screens flow

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am reading on JEST but what I would like to know is if you guys know any librairies/ testing frameworks that I could use to simulate screen navigations based on all the available paths.

Like for a new user:

1. Welcome Screen -> Login Screen -> Register screen -> Main App screen
2. (User already logged in ) Main App Screen
3. Main App Screen -> User Profile screen

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not voting this as off topic, even though it sounds opinion based. Instead I'm answering this because this is not really opinion based, as there is a strongly preferred lib in the RN community (strongly preferred by far).

That is called end-to-end testing, you would use Detox for that.

Here's a great article - https://pillow.codes/testing-in-react-native-jest-detox-d7b3b79a166a

More on detox - https://blog.home.ht/how-to-do-end-to-end-testing-on-react-native-with-detox-2b7f404e7713

And a general article on most popluar test methods - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-front-end-test-pyramid-rethink-your-testing-3b343c2bca5 - we see that with detox and jest we have all three covered: unit, snapshot, and e2e.

Comment: Thanks Noitidart. I also show a youtube video about detox and this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @AvinashLingaloo may you please share that youtube video, I am interested.

Comment: Thanks Avinash thats a nice vid! Thats about redux though, not detox.

Comment: It is in the same conference NEXT 2017.. I missed up the vids : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgFFeI70PWw

Comment: Thanks Avinash, nice vid

Answer (score 0):

Jest is for unit testing. For testing navigation, maybe, we need to do functional testing using a tool like [Appium](http://appium.io/getting-started.html).

With Jest, you can easily test individual components or screens. But for navigation flow, I recommend Appium or similar for UI testing.